# Firebase orderByChild Order Is Not Correct

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1. My Sample Data

[image: Sample firebase data]

2. Code

   ```
         let users_ref = firebase_instance.database().ref('users');

     let amount_of_data = 4;
     let limit_users_ref = users_ref.orderByChild("score").limitToLast(amount_of_data);

     limit_users_ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {


       snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

         var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
         var childData = childSnapshot.val();

         console.log([childKey, childData]);
       });


     })
   ```
3. Output I am getting

   [image: Output result]

As it can be seen on output, the data is not ordered. I should be getting test1 in stead of test3 there. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: As Doug answered, you're storing your numerical values as strings, so Firebase does a lexicographical sort. And in lexicographical ordering `"2"`, comes before `"10"`, just like `"aap"` comes before `"n"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732340/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762297/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174300/firebase-query-ordering-not-working-properly/37192471#37192471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scores are strings.  They should be numbers instead.  Strings don't sort like numbers.