# Fetch Top 100 Scores from Firebase and Display them in Xcode TableView using Swift4

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

My data tree is organized like so:

- users

  - user id generated by firebase

    - userHighScore: "100"
    - userName: "Sally"
    - userNation: "USA"
  - another user id generated by firebase

    - userHighScore: "92"
    - userName: "Jim"
    - userNation: "Canada"
      etc

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Firebase]

I'd like to fetch the info of the users with the top 100 scores from Firebase and display the userName, userNation, and userHighScore in a TableView (starting with the highest score first).

I have a TableView set up on my TopScoreViewController.swift and have it connected as "@IBOutlet var topScoreTableView: UITableView!"

I've also control+dragged from the table up into the yellow button so that it's set as both dataSource and delegate.

In the table, there's 1 Prototype Cell, and I dragged in a label.

I've added a new file called TopScoreTableViewCell.swift and connected the label in the prototype cell as "@IBOutlet var userNameLabel: UILabel!"

So far so good (I think).

But from here, but nothing seems to be working. I've found lots of articles about different pieces of this but I haven't yet had success in putting it all together.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing code, there's not a whole lot we can do to see what you might be doing wrong.  But I can tell you right now that since your scores are stored as strings rather than numbers, they will not sort in numeric order.

Comment: Also see this question we just got: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916534/firebase-orderbychild-order-is-not-correct and the one I closed it against.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Doug! I will see if I can get those saved as Int rather than string.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I will take a look at those.

Comment: The code you need is almost in the documentation see [Work with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) and check out the code snippet there. Combine with `.queryOrdered(byChild:` and you have the answer.